# Как правильно сконфигурировать Spring Boot приложение?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Изучаю спринг по русскому переводу книжке Крейга(Spring в действии), и столкнулся со странным поведением (может я что-то не знаю).

Вместо ручной конфигурации, отдал её на откуп самому фреймворку, вроде работает как надо, но
По какой то странной причине он попросту не видит папку static внутри resources (хотя templates видит)

```
src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── sus
│   │   │       ├── ChatApplication.java
│   │   │       ├── configs
│   │   │       │   └── SecurityConfig.java
│   │   │       │   
│   │   │       ├── controllers
│   │   │       │   ├── BaseController.java
│   │   │       │   └── PilotController.java
│   │   │       ├── model
│   │   │       │   ├── Pilot.java
│   │   │       │   ├── PilotWeapon.java
│   │   │       │   ├── Titan.java
│   │   │       │   └── TitanWeapon.java
│   │   │       ├── repository
│   │   │       │   └── PilotRepository.java
│   │   │       └── services
│   │   │           └── PilotService.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.properties
│   │       ├── static
│   │       │   └── abobus.html
│   │       └── templates
│   │           ├── home.html
│   │           ├── pilots
│   │           │   └── home.html
│   │           ├── scripts
│   │           │   └── script.js
│   │           └── styles
│   │               └── style.css
```

структура src папки если нужно

Я попробовал добавить папку static вручную через webmvcconfigurer, однако это так же не помогло. Надеюсь на вашу подсказку!

Comment: Почитайте https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ!
Дело в том что метод возвращающий название html документа для отображения не был помечен нотацией @ResponseBody (не совсем понял для чего она, но хотя бы проблему решил)